# What is a good technique to light up vast areas quickly?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-worldedit

I have a Bukkit server, and in part of that server I loaded on the [Star Ship Enterprise](http://www.minecraftworldmap.com/worlds/iZtzJ#/248/64/213/-5/0/0).

One of the things I still get annoyed by is mobs spawning where they shouldn't. I think the best low-complexity and future-proof solution is to use lighting to prevent spawning where I don't want it.

So, when I find a large dark room, how should I light it? Running all over the room and adding torches is slow. Since I run a Bukkit server, it is very easy for me to install plugins. I already installed WorldEdit.

I am very much OK with installing additional plugins to add the lighting, because the lighting can continue to do its job long after the plugin is removed.

Can you provide me with some helpful information to accomplish the task of lighting up large empty rooms? And can you suggest how I would light up with non-level surfaces? (like the sloped roof of the Enterprise, and of the interior rooms)

I don't mind using extra torches, but don't want it to be too crowded for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: You would be better off using a multi-world plugin and a mob-control plugin, then putting the Enterprise in its own world with spawning turned off. In fact, you'd be better off (and less likely to see the question closed) by simply asking "How can I stop mobs spawning in my Enterprise without disabling spawning in the rest of my world?" instead of assuming what the best solution is. That's our job, remember? ;)